# Could not convert from ‘QAction*’ to ‘QAction’

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt4

I get this error in my smtdplugin implementation file , when i try to return value. OK so i understand that i'm creating a pointer to an QAction , and when i try to return it , i can not do that because my method is waiting a reference to an object. But i dont know how to act (i'm a begginer)
How to avoid this issue ? , and with success to return that object

```
#include "smtdplugin.h"

QAction SmtdPlugin::newItem() {

QAction *item = new QAction(NULL);

    return item; // here i get error
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(smtdplugin,SmtdPlugin);
```

Header file :

```
#ifndef SMTDPLUGIN_H
#define SMTDPLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAction>
#include "smtdinterface.h"

class SmtdPlugin : public QObject,SmtdInterface  {

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES (SmtdInterface)

public :
    QAction newItem();

};

#endif // SMTDPLUGIN_H
```

Interface class  :

```
#ifndef SMTDINTERFACE_H
#define SMTDONINTERFACE_H

#include <QAction>

class SmtdInterface {

public:
    virtual ~SmtdInterface() {}
    SmtdInterface();
    virtual QAction newItem () = 0;

};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(SmtdInterface,"com.trololo.Plugin.SmtdInterface/1.0")

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `return item`, you are returning a pointer to `QAction`, but according to the function's declaration you return a `QAction`, hence the error.

So, you should do:

```
QAction* SmtdPlugin::newItem() {

    QAction *item = new QAction(NULL);

    return item;
}
```

Comment: As the answer solves problem, I won't downvote it. Downvote would come for first suggestion. QAction is QObject, so it can't be copied. And your return statement would try to make a copy, and fail to compile

Comment: Please remove your first sugestion as it is invalid

Answer (score 2):

I amn't familiar with qt but the error is -

```
QAction* SmtdPlugin::newItem()   // Return type should be QAction* and not QAction
{

    QAction *item = new QAction(NULL);

    return item;
}
```

The type of `item` is **QAction*** and not **QAction** which is what compiler is complaining about. I think you are confused about the space.

```
QAction* item ; // QAction * item ; QAction *item ;
```

All the above three conventions mean the same.

Comment: In your case, you are returning a pointer to an object but the return type of the member function says it returns an object. A pointer to an object and the object it self are two different types and aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create the action on the heap then it's probably best just to change the return value to QAction*.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you return an item which is of type `QAction*`:

```
return item; // here i get error
```

but your function signature requires that you return QAction:

```
QAction SmtdPlugin::newItem() {
```

To solve the conflict, either change function signature to

```
QAction* SmtdPlugin::newItem() {
```

or
change the concept of your function so that it does not eturn a pointer any more.